# Automatically capitialize things in datagrip

Tags: datagrip

Is there a way in datagrip to automatically capitialize key words even if they are typed in lowercase? For example SELECT, FROM , WHERE , HAVING, ORDER BY?

Comment: Before I answer, just to clarify: do you use code completion? Because completion items are capitalized already if the corresponding setting is on.

Comment: I think it may have somehow gotten turned off. Either way, the desired behavior is to see it come through with key words in all caps. Not sure what code completion is.

Comment: Code completion is intelli-sense. Also, when formatting code you get the needed case, right?

Comment: I have never tried the code formating tools. I have my own preference for formatting, so i do it manually

Comment: After time gone by, it is actually best to go into code style like the answer says. You can do a lot of customization.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

File - Settings - Editor - Code Style - SQL - General - Case - Keywords: To upper

Comment: Also check your specific dialect to ensure you are using the General Settings